# concept of conjugacy class in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-algebras

Can we think of a similar concept of a conjugacy class in a ring which satisfies two three properties like conjugacy classes.

I think of a set $M_x={xyx^{-1}-y}$ for $x\in R$ and $R$ is a division ring but not yet able to establish any useful property.

Comment: Which of the properties are you looking to have satisfied?

Comment: Like if partitions the ring.

Comment: Your choice seems odd. Elements will generally not be "conjugate" to themselves with that choice (if the ring is a field you just get $0$ for everything).

Comment: I'm thinking of voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" unless you clarify sometime soon